# Docker and NPM install

Tags: docker, npm

Out of curiosity. Can the `^`version for dependencies in the package.json cause the `npm install` layer to be re-run by Docker.

Given a docker file like

```
FROM `SOME_BASE`

COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps --force
```

Could having the dependencies versions with `^` or any semver prefix versioning cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker doesn't know anything about the contents of the files it `COPY`s into images.  It saves a hash of their contents but that's it.

With the Dockerfile you've shown, if you run `docker build` twice, the `npm i` command will be re-run if the base image has changed or the contents of `package.json` have changed.  If neither thing has changed, then it will reuse the cached application dependencies from the previous build.  The form of semver constraint you use doesn't matter here.

It's usually a good practice to also copy the `package-lock.json` file into the image.  Regardless of what you have listed in `package.json`, the lock file will include the exact package versions that are used.  This makes questions like this a little clearer: the lock file has to list the same exact package versions for the cached `node_modules` to be used.